# A simple linq query

Tags: vb.net, linq

Here is  the situation: I have huge amount of data stored in 'mysamples' as the below data structure. I need to do some query and reporting job on the data and I am new to Linq. To start with, I need to write a Linq script to extract the monthly year-to-date report for all records. It is to sum up the 'value' of all samplepoints (in the current year, categorized by month) of all samples in 'mysamples'. I can easily do it in vb.net code, but I realized that Linq is the right tool for this kinda stuff. Can anybody give me something to start with. Thanks.

```
Public Structure sample
    Public Property id As String
    Public datapoints As List(Of sampledatapoint)
End Structure

Public Structure sampledatapoint
    Public time As DateTime
    Public value As Decimal
End Structure

Public mysamples As New List(Of sample)
```

Comment: give some input data and expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim sampleQ1 as New sample() With {.id ="2016Q1", .datapoints = New List(Of sampledatapoint)()}
    sampleQ1.datapoints.Add(New sampledatapoint() With {.time = New DateTime(2016, 1, 1), .value = 1000})
    sampleQ1.datapoints.Add(New sampledatapoint() With {.time = New DateTime(2016, 1, 10), .value = 2000})
    sampleQ1.datapoints.Add(New sampledatapoint() With {.time = New DateTime(2016, 2, 1), .value = 500})
    sampleQ1.datapoints.Add(New sampledatapoint() With {.time = New DateTime(2016, 3, 7), .value = 750})

    Dim sampleQ2 as New sample() With {.id ="2016Q2", .datapoints = New List(Of sampledatapoint)()}
    sampleQ2.datapoints.Add(New sampledatapoint() With {.time = New DateTime(2016, 4, 4), .value = 800})
    sampleQ2.datapoints.Add(New sampledatapoint() With {.time = New DateTime(2016, 4, 5), .value = 150})

    Dim sampleQ4 as New sample() With {.id ="2015Q4", .datapoints = New List(Of sampledatapoint)()}
    sampleQ4.datapoints.Add(New sampledatapoint() With {.time = New DateTime(2015, 10, 20), .value = 666})

    Dim mysamples As New List(Of sample)  
    mysamples.Add((sampleQ1))
    mysamples.Add((sampleQ2))
    mysamples.Add((sampleQ4))

    Dim q = From sdp In mysamples.SelectMany(Function(x) x.datapoints).Where(Function(x) x.time.Year = DateTime.Now.Year)
            Group By grp = sdp.time.Month Into Group
            Select New With {.Month = grp, .Sum = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.value)}

    For Each monthlySum In q
        Console.WriteLine("Month: {0}, Sum: {1}", monthlySum.Month, monthlySum.Sum)
    Next

    'Month: 1, Sum: 3000
    'Month: 2, Sum: 500
    'Month: 3, Sum: 750
    'Month: 4, Sum: 950
```

`SelectMany` does the trick. It flattens all sampledatapoints of all samples into one list. The `Group By` remains the same.

Additionally: is there any reason why you use `struct` instead of `class`? I would suggest to use a class at least for `sample` since it neither represents a single value nor does it contain value types.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Can you also help me on step more ... See my original post, the list of samledatapoint is one of the variable of class "sample". I probably need further filtering with regarding to sample.id as well. Can you show me how to wrap the sample data structure in the query?

Comment: Do you want all sampledatapoints from all samples regardless their id? or do you want it to be grouped by id? or filtered to a specific id?

Comment: All data is stored in a big list "mysamples" as list of sample. Yes all sampledatapoints from all samples regardless their id.

Comment: Updated in respect to your comments

Comment: Very useful to learn the SelectMany trick. It bothered me for a while. Yep, the sample should be a class. Thanks again